# Finding trips in a set of waypoints

Tags: gps, data-mining, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

From a set of waypoints, each with lat/lon and timestamp, how do you find out the start and end point of a trip vs. staying at a place over time?

I'm playing with Google Latitude data, unfortunately it only provides a stack of locations, no meta data. I tried to calculate the average velocity between waypoints, but because of the nature of Latitude sometimes location data gets slightly inaccurate and it looks like I stopped somewhere even though I was still on a trip to somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I guess staying at a place over time is just a matter of degree, isn't it?

Given a bunch of lat/long pairs with timestamps, you can do the following:

- Figure out the first and last points
- Figure out what order the points were visited in
- Figure out the difference between successive waypoints

But if this is all you have, this is all you have.  Some questions you don't know the answer to:

- Are any waypoints missing?
- Are the waypoints entered by the system/user at consistent times?
- Are the first/last points the user's primary residence?
- Are the waypoints accurate?  (Did the user make a transcription error somewhere?)

If you have a set of waypoints that may be several trips, I suppose you can take some time cutoff to bin your trips (a gap of a few weeks probably means separate trips).

Otherwise, the earliest and latest points are probably your best bets.

Comment: The set also includes accuracy for each point, I forgot to mention that. However if you're staying at a location the velocity between the points is likely to drop. The difficulty though is if accuracy also drops and puts you quickly a few meters/kilometers away (even though you're staying at the same place) it looks like you're suddenly moving again, which is not the case. I wonder if somebody wrote an algorithm for my case...

Comment: So your use case implies regular updates (once a minute, say) rather than user-initiated updates ("I'll tell the service I'm here now")?

Comment: Google Latitude updates more or less every hour if you're staying at a place and more frequently when you're moving. The updating though depends on battery life and some other factors on the phone.